# Error while building rosjava.jar

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have problem building rosjava.jar.

i tried to rosmake rosjava. and then ant dist. these are the errors i get:

after rosmake,
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dependencies.xml'

after ant dist,
BUILD FAILED
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosjava_core/rosjava/build.xml:6: Cannot find /opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosjava_core/rosjava/dependencies.xml imported from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosjava_core/rosjava/build.xml

Please help. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11183/error-while-building-rosjava.jar/) by [sskk89](https://answers.ros.org/users/1070/sskk89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2011-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you install rosjava from debian packages, it has already been built and is read-only.  Thus, you cannot run 'ant dist' anymore -- there should already be a jar file inside of rosjava_core that you can use in your projects.

EDIT: Also check that your debian packages are up-to-date with:

```
apt-get install ros-electric-rosjava-core
```

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sskk89](https://answers.ros.org/users/1070/sskk89/) on 2011-09-13**:
reinstalling from debian solves the problem. Thanks for helping! It helps alot! life saver!

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-13**:
Installing from debian packages means running 'apt-get install ros-electric-rosjava-core'.  If you did that and are in the situation you are, I'm not sure what happened.  I'm going to attempt to do another release of rosjava today.

**Comment by [sskk89](https://answers.ros.org/users/1070/sskk89/) on 2011-09-12**:
I don't see the 'dist' folder inside /opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosjava_core/rosjava

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-09-12**:
It looks like you already installed it from debian packages. Does `ls  ls /opt/ros/electric/stacks/rosjava_core/rosjava/dist` show `rosjava.jar`? If yes, it's installed correctly.

**Comment by [sskk89](https://answers.ros.org/users/1070/sskk89/) on 2011-09-12**:
how do I install rosjava from debian packages? i can't find the jar file inside rosjava_core. thanks for the reply